# Multiple List Views?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-listview

I'm trying to display high scores for a game I'm creating, with two columns, one for their name, and the other for the amount of moves it took them to complete the game.

Currently it is all stored in a SQLiteDatabase and presented in a list view, where it appears as one column in the format

name,moves

But I'd like to get the moves on the opposite of the screen, would this require multiple list views or would it require editing of the one list view, or its adapter?

The code currently used is:

```
        datasource = new HighScoreDataSource(this);
    datasource.open(); //Open the connection

    List<HighScore> values = datasource.getAllHighScores(); //Retrieve all the data

    //Using a simple cursor adapted to show the elements
    ArrayAdapter<HighScore> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<HighScore>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a row layout with two `TextViews` placed the way you want and implement a simple custom `ArrayAdapter`:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HighScore> {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            List<HighScore> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_row_layout, parent, false);
        }
        HighScore item = getItem(position); 
        TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_id_textview);
        name.setText(/*get the name from the item HighScore object*/);
        TextView moves = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.moves_id_textview);
        moves.setText(/*get the moves from the item HighScore object*/);
        return convertView;
    }       

}
```

Another option is to break your `List<HighScore> values` in a List of `HashMaps`(containing two entries, one for name and one for moves) and use a [`SimpleAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html)(with the row layout above).